# Date formatting with .long or .full not resulting in hours/minutes/days/seconds

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the current date as a string showing granularity down to hours/minutes/seconds, however the following code will only show "Friday Jan 20th, 2017". I've tried with a dateStyle of none, .medium, .long, .full. They only display a granularity down to the nearest day, how can I get finer granularity than that?

```
    let dateFormatter       = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    let now                 = Date()
    let dateString          = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a `timeStyle` as well. Example (German locale):

```
let dateFormatter       = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
let now                 = Date()
let dateString          = dateFormatter.string(from: now)

print(dateString) // Freitag, 20. Januar 2017 um 18:39:04
```

Alternatively, set a `dateFormat`. Example:

```
let dateFormatter       = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "EEEE ddMMMyyyy HHmmss",
                                                    options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
let now                 = Date()
let dateString          = dateFormatter.string(from: now)

print(dateString) // Freitag, 20. Jan. 2017, 18:46:36
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! you also need to give the `DateFormatter` a `timeStyle`.

```
let dateFormatter       = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
dateFormatter.timeStlye = .full // options of short, medium, long, and full
let now                 = Date()
let dateString          = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
```

`.full` from the above prints `Friday, January 20, 2017 at 12:40:23 PM Eastern Standard Time`

Answer (score 0):

In order to see different time style you will need to set a value for the timeStyle on the dateFormatter. e.g

```
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .full
```

The following formats work for timeStyle as well as dateStyle

```
case none
case short
case medium
case long
case full
```

See Apple's docs if you want to learn more about date formatters. 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter